# Create Point cloud from geometry?

Tags: python, 3d, geometry, shader

I want to make a 3d point cloud from 3d modeling file(dae, obj...) using python code.
like http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4c/Point_cloud_torus.gif
I have no idea where to begin. Do I need polygon or mesh data or something?
If there were any algorithm for this let me help.
I saw many questions about create mesh from point cloud but it`s very hard to find about this topic.
thanks.

Comment: First of all, try to think about building a point cloud of a single triangle. Then just expand this idea for a set of triangles which is excatly a polygonal mesh.

Comment: The OBJ file contain polygon mesh vertices data. You can directly use these vertices data as points for the point cloud. You will need to sample more points from triangles of the polygon mesh if the there are not too many vertices. To sample points from a triangle, you can use Barycentric coordinates to evaluate new points.